# What is the correct way to add an asynchronous event handler with default parameters?

Tags: javascript, async-await, dom-events, fetch-api

I registered a 'click' event listener `fetchAsync` to the first button labelled `Fetch async`. The event listener performs an HTTP POST using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and reports the status. This seems to work correctly. The second button labelled `Fetch async with default parameters` is almost identical except that the event listener `fetchAsyncDefault` contains default parameters `url` and `data`. This causes the fetch to fail with error `TypeError: Failed to fetch` and a CSP error `Refused to connect to 'http://localhost:3000/[object%20PointerEvent]'` on the console.

I have prepared a [simple demonstration repo](https://github.com/shanemcandrewai/projour/tree/so/docs) with code pasted below.

What is the correct way to add an asynchronous event handler with default parameters?

### fetchtest.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Fetch test</title>
    <script src="/javascripts/fetchtest.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Fetch test</h1>
    <p id="status">status</p>
    <p id="return">return</p>
    <input id="fetchAsync" type="button" value="Fetch async" />
    <input id="fetchAsyncDefault" type="button" value="Fetch async with default parameters" />
  </body>
</html>
```

### javascripts/fetchtest.js

```
const fetchAsync = async () => {
  const url = 'https://httpbin.org/post';
  const data = { node1: 'val1', node2: 'val2' };
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });
    const ret = await response.json();
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'success';
    document.getElementById('return').innerHTML = ret.data;
  } catch (error) {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'failed';
    document.getElementById('return').innerHTML = error;
  }
};

const fetchAsyncDefault = async (
  url = 'https://httpbin.org/post',
  data = { node1: 'val1', node2: 'val2' },
) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });
    const ret = await response.json();
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'success';
    document.getElementById('return').innerHTML = ret.data;
  } catch (error) {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'failed';
    document.getElementById('return').innerHTML = error;
  }
};

document.getElementById('fetchAsync').addEventListener('click', fetchAsync);
document.getElementById('fetchAsyncDefault').addEventListener('click', fetchAsyncDefault);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback to `.addEventListener` is called with an event of the type that is being listened for.

```js
const fn = (arg) => {
  console.log(arg instanceof Event);
};
window.addEventListener('click', fn);
```

If you add a listener by doing

```
.addEventListener('click', fetchAsyncDefault);
```

then a click event will be passed to `fetchAsyncDefault` as the first parameter - which is causing your problem here.

If you want to explicitly pass zero arguments to the handler so that the default ones get used, do

```
document.getElementById('fetchAsyncDefault').addEventListener('click', () => fetchAsyncDefault());
```

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance, I see now this single `Event` parameter is [documented on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#usage_notes)